# Adding img to random div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to randomly add an image tag to a div, so for this is what I have it should work but doesn't display the character on a tile.

```
var $divs = $(".mapsquare");
$("#player").appendTo( $divs.get(Math.floor(Math.random() * $divs.length)) );

<div id="1_1" class="mapsquare"></div>
<div id="2_1" class="mapsquare"></div>
<div id="3_1" class="mapsquare"></div>
<div id="4_1" class="mapsquare"></div>
<div id="5_1" class="mapsquare"></div>
```

Strong example what I have so far on JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/zCZkA/

Comment: just an FYI, `.player` in your css will not match your div with `id=player`, you'll want `#player` instead.

Comment: Thanks crafty one slipped through thanks!

Comment: another note. use `$divs.length - 1`. since you are using the index which starts at 0

Comment: it should work as is - if `divs.length` is 1, the expression resolves to `get(0)`; if `divs.length` is 2, it resolves to `get(0)` or `get(1)` etc, as intended

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with

```
<div id="player"></div>
```

instead of

```
<div id="player>"></div>
```

;)

http://jsfiddle.net/avqaq/

Comment: I can't believe I did that, looks like I need a Coffee thanks!